# HIGHGUI error while using opencv to stream video from eye toy webcam

Tags: opencv, video, computer-vision, webcam, linux-device-driver

I am a beginner to use OpenCV right now. I am trying to stream video from a webcam (eye toy webcam) using OpenCV libraries. I know that the webcam is working fine because I used VLC to stream video and it was working fine. I have the following program:

```
int main(){
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
             break;
        }

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_CROPCAP
Frame size: 640x480
select timeout
```

I am sure that the the error is thrown when the device is being attached using VideoCapture. I have searched a lot on the net but could not find explanation for this specific error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine. Are you sure you have configured your openCV library properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287488/runtime-opencv-highgui-error-highgui-error-v4l-v4l2-vidioc-s-crop-opencv-c

Comment: open a terminal type gstreamer-properties click enter
click video try v4l1 and v4l2
click the bottom test buton for each 1
and do not open cheese

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455700

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Sohaib. I ran gstreamer-properties and it seemed to do something with the webcam (I could again see the activity LED glowing), but there was no video stream. Is that supposed to happen. I am now inclining towards re configuring the OpenCV libraries. Will let you know how that works out.

Comment: There was no video stream when you ran your program?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by installing: libv4l-dev then recompiling opencv. Check your cmake output to make sure that V4L is actually being linked in properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following links:

[1. Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287488/runtime-opencv-highgui-error-highgui-error-v4l-v4l2-vidioc-s-crop-opencv-c)

[2. Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455700)

The problem could be with your webcam.

Answer (score 0):

I haved the some error when trying to execute a code that does facedetection , i solved it by adding the files needed in my working folder (source folder). you can show us the entire code to find out what exactly you need .