# OpenCV 3.0.0 Error: The Function is not implemented (Only in Release Mode)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to execute the very first example from OpenCV 3.0.0 tutorials and I can't get it to work in Release Mode. Everything is fine with Debug Mode.

This is the error I get in Release Mode:

```
C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\x64\Release>test.exe ../../image01.png
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file D:\OpenCV\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 522
```

I know it could be something on Properties > Linker inside Visual Studio 2013 but I can't see what.

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716625/cvnamedwindow-function-not-implemented-unable-to-launch-libhand) but it didn't help as Cmake-gui shows exactly this:

```
 GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO
```

Meaning I do have support for GUI in Windows. I just don't know why it doesn't work in Release Mode.

The configs on Properties inside Visual Studio 2013 are analogous for Release and Debug Modes.

Please, ask me further info if you need.

Comment: I assume you wanted to tag for Visual-Studio-2013 instead of Visual-Studio-2012.

Comment: Are you using the libraries/dlls from the vc12 folder of opencv?

Comment: Also are you using the Release libs / dlls in Release mode?

Comment: Yes, The tag was for Visual-Studio-2013. I'll try to change it. Also, the dlls in Release mode are the Release dlls (without the d in the end) 
and from the vc12 folder.