# The following packages have unmet dependencies OpenCV 3.2 Python 3.5

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I was trying an OpenCV tutorial and when I run the python code I got this error

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /home/pankaja/Desktop/OpenCV-tmp/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 611
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pankaja/PycharmProjects/ImageProcessing/imageprocess.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.error: /home/pankaja/Desktop/OpenCV-tmp/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:611: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

So as for [OpenCV error: the function is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655969/opencv-error-the-function-is-not-implemented) this stackoverflow answer I tried the command **sudo apt-get install libopencv-*** and got this,

```
*The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-apps-dev : Depends: libcv-bridge-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libdynamic-reconfigure-config-init-mutex-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libimage-transport-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libnodeletlib-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libroscpp-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-highgui-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*
```

How to solve this? What have I done wrong ?

Edit 1 : after I run **sudo apt-get install -f** as @Jeru Luke mentioned

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libenca0 librubberband2v5 libva-wayland1 linux-headers-4.10.0-27 linux-headers-4.10.0-27-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-30
  linux-headers-4.10.0-30-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-89 linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-92 linux-headers-4.4.0-92-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-27-generic linux-image-4.10.0-30-generic linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-27-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-89-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-27-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-30-generic mpv rtmpdump
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

still getting the error when I run **sudo apt-get install libopencv-***

Edit 2 : After run the **sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev** command as @Zindarod mentioned

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.18.9-1ubuntu3) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
                Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (= 3.18.9-1ubuntu3) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
                Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libepoxy-dev (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libwayland-dev (>= 1.5.91) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libmirclient-dev (>= 0.13.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

still no luck

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix broken or missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the help, 
I tried that already, but this is what I got

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
.
.
.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.


And still when I run this command **sudo apt-get install libopencv-***
I'm getting the same error

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`

Comment: @Zindarod 
Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.18.9-1ubuntu3) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
                Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (= 3.18.9-1ubuntu3) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
                Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libepoxy-dev (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libwayland-dev (>= 1.5.91) but it is not going to be installed..
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana adding these comments in the question as an edit would be helpful

Comment: @JeruLuke I edited the question, Thanks

Comment: I struggled with this same error during this past week. Unfortunatelly, I am not sure what solved it...
But, I ended up compiling OpenCV itself and these are all the prerequisites I am installing.

"RUN apt-get install -y build-essential cmake pkg-config
 libjpeg8-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
 libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
 libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
 libgtk-3-dev
 libatlas-base-dev gfortran
 python2.7-dev python3.5-dev
 wget zip"

Comment: It was a bit trial and error. And I think the article from [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) is, more or less, what I ended up following.

Comment: @Pedro I solved that unment dependency problem by installing the pckages using **sudo aptitude install** so, that's no longer a problem. But still I'm getting the error when I run python code. I have installed libgtk2.0-dev already. But still having the error