# Reinstall OpenCV from Scratch

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I'm having an error in OpenCV when I try to run a python code. I tried running

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("watch.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I'm getting this error.

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /home/pankaja/Desktop/OpenCV-tmp/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 611
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pankaja/PycharmProjects/ImageProcessing/imageprocess.py", line 8, in 
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.error: /home/pankaja/Desktop/OpenCV-tmp/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:611: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage

with some errors finally I managed to install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config ([The following packages have unmet dependencies OpenCV 3.2 Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041377/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-opencv-3-2-python-3-5)), but still the it's giving the error

So, now I think of doing to do a fresh installation on both python 3.5 and OpenCV to fix the problem. How can I uninstall OpenCV completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem once. I fixed the problem by completely uninstalling opencv and reinstalling it from source. There are some dependencies  like ffmpeg you should install.

EDIT:
To completely uninstall opencv

1. If you installed from source you can use the following command

   `make uninstall`

run This command from build directory of the opencv source.

2. If you installed using pip

   `sudo pip uninstall opencv`
3. If you Installed using apt-get

   `sudo apt-get remove python-opencv`

   `sudo apt-get purge python-opencv`

I hope this might help

Comment: I've installed OpenCV using the source. So I ran **make uninstall** . Now when I ran **import cv2** in python3 it says **ImportError: No module named 'cv2'** but there are some folders and files left in usr/ directory (when I searched openCV there are files/folders left) . Is it mean that uninstallation is failed ?

Comment: Is it ok delete them manually? Because there's so many [this image of them](http://imgur.com/a/T5txU) , I'm bit scared as I've done somethings before that almost killed my hard drive. Anyway, appreciate your help

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana you can safely delete these two folders. /usr/local/share/OpenCV and /usr/local/include/opencv

Comment: I deleted those folders and installed OpenCV again on a virtual environment and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error for a couple of weeks.So I decided to reinstall the opencv just like you did.

First,`sudo pip uninstall opencv`
or if you installed through apt-get,`sudo apt-get remove python-opencv`
After that,`pip install opencv-contrib-python`
It worked like a charm.Only getting error in video processing.Guess that would take a week to rectify that.

Source:[See this if you need any clarification](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python)