# Is there an alternative to cv2.namedWindow() and cv2.destroywindow()?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am searching for an alternative command for `cv2.namedWindow()` and `cv2.destroyWindow()` as there's an issue with the GTK +2 support.

I have already tried to sort out the issue on the error:

> "OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.
>   Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
>   are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
>   re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file
>   /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 565"

of GTK support (from the answers on stackoverflow[[OpenCV error: the function is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655969/opencv-error-the-function-is-not-implemented])).

But as no success was achieved, I thought of using an alternative for `cv2.namedWindow()` and `cv2.destryoWindow()`.

However, I could not find any alternatives to the above.

It would be great if someone could suggest me the right library.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic here. Pick any GUI toolkit you like. (For example Python includes tkinter by default)

Comment: okay, thanks. Will do that.